# Is it possible to color a(n) background/container/image/object partially?

Tags: java, android, xml, colors, background

I'm making a skill points calculator app for a game and I want the background of an activty (or some other kind of container) to be colored to which tier the player can invest points.

[Image example](http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/original/1/16324/1192543-picture1.png)

As you can see, the left skill tree is only colored to where the player is allowed to spend points.

I already thoroughly searched the android documentation and forums, but without any luck.

Does anyone know if this is possible, or has someone another idea with which I can achieve my goal.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you are looking for, you can apply a ShapeDrawable to ANY view in Android (meaning extends the *android.view* package.

This class will allow you to generate simple 2D shapes, which can be applied as a *background* to any *view*

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html